# How can I make a custom WinPE?

Tags: winpe

I should make a custom winpe that :

- Have an automatic IP Address such as 192.168.17.253/24
- and after the system booted up, it could ping the another IP Address such as : 192.168.17.243

Comment: custom how?  build in more drivers?  You could modify the startup.cmd file if you just wanted to ping.

Comment: yah, should make changes in startup.cmd, but i am starter in winpe and dont know it enough

Comment: please explain further what you mean by a custom PE?

Comment: I mean a customized WinPE that have those 2 characters that i said above.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/83722-how-to-make-a-basic-winpe-20-cd/

This should get you started.  Despite the instructions mentioning XP and Vista the **Windows AIK** has been updated for windows 7/8.  The same steps should work.